# Borel $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the family of open sets, does that mean that every Borel set is essentially some countable union/intersection of open sets or a complement of open sets?

The idea is quite similar to the concept of generated field extensions in field theory, where the field $K(\alpha)$ is a field extension  generated by $\alpha$ over $K$. and we see that every element is essentially a quotient of linear combinations of powers of $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes to the first question; and no to the second.

Comment: I didn't ask a second  question :P

Comment: There are two question-marks in your question ;)?

Comment: ohh,so you mean no the fact that it doesn't apply to $\sigma$-algebras? The second question was merely  reinforcing my earlier question and was just restating it and since you said yes to my first question i assume that every borel set is a countable union/intersection.... is a true statement. I think I will just delete the second qsn since it just adds more confusion

Comment: Well, borel sets are sets, so there is no concept of linearity there...unfortunately.

Comment: Look up Borel hierarchy